# Use PAM to authenticate UserB when program launched from userA

Tags: c, linux, authentication, ubuntu, pam

I've build a program in C, I run it on Ubuntu.
I'm using PAM to authenticate users, e.g. I launch a client, the client sends username and password, the server authenticate the user.
The problem is that if I launch, from userA, the program that makes the PAM authentication, I can only authenticate userA, while if I try to authenticate userB I get:

`Failure in pam authentication: Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info`

I can solve this only if I run the program with `sudo`, but I don't think that's the appropriate approach?

Here's a summary of how I use PAM as of now:

```
pam_handle_t *handle = NULL;
const char *service_name = "myservice";
int retval;
char *username;

retval = pam_start(service_name, NULL, &conv, &handle); // &conv is a pointer to the struct with the standard/default misc_conv function
if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS){
    ...
}

retval = pam_authenticate(handle, 0);
if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS) {
    ...
}
```

I've also this file in pam.d folder:

```
auth        required        pam_unix.so
auth        required        pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=group sense=allow file=/etc/login.group.allowed
account     required        pam_unix.so
```

Comment: Surely your program's behavior with respect to PAM depends on the specifics of how it uses the PAM API, and also on the relevant PAM configuration.  Without these, in the form of a [mre], there's not much we can say.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've added the code, and more details, in the first post. Please if you need more information, let me know.

Comment: What is "the standard/default misc_conv function" noted in the code comment?  The third argument to `pam_start()` should be a pointer to a `struct pam_conv` object that exists and is managed by the caller -- not a function pointer.

Comment: And that underscores the fact that although the additional information helps, the question still does not present an MRE.  If it did, then I would not have to ask about `conv`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger this is the misc_conv I'm talking about: https://linux.die.net/man/3/misc_conv

Comment: Again, the third argument to `pam_start` should not be a function pointer.  It should be a pointer to a `struct pam_conv` (which contains a function pointer as its first member).

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks I've fixed the question! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can solve this only if I run the program with sudo, but I don't think that's the appropriate approach?

You are using the `pam_unix` module in the authentication stack for your service.  That is useful only when the program invoking authentication through PAM is privileged, because `pam_unix` needs to access the system's secure credential store (the `/etc/shadow` file, or a secure authentication service such as sssd) -- with the possible exception of authenticating the already-authenticated user associated with the current session.  That's why it works when you run the application via `sudo`, but not when you run it as an ordinary user.

In a sense, then, running the application with `sudo` **is** the right approach.  You need privilege to authenticate a user against the system's authentication database, and that's a good way to get it.

Another, more risky, way to obtain the needed privilege would be to make the program SUID-root, or to give it the appropriate [capabilities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).  If you went this way then you would want the program to drop unneeded privileges as soon as possible.  This is the way a system service with such a need would normally do it.

But if you're not writing a system service then the best answer is probably **just don't**.  A regular user who wants to assume the identity of a different user should use the `su` or `sudo` command to do so, or should just log in as that user in the first place.  That would moot the need for your application to authenticate a different user.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm still confused about something. As I said, I've a client/server program, let's imagine something like a custom made FTP service for teaching purposes. In the server, I've the program that runs the PAM authentication. To my understanding, it seems appropriate to run that server program as non-sudo, so it seems appropriate to launch that program as userA (or nobody, or something like this, it's a daemon basically) and then allow userB to authenticate. Running the whole server program as sudo seems quite off from a security point of view, am I wrong?

Comment: @testermaster, the principle you seem to be getting at is that programs should run with the fewest privileges necessary to do the needed work.  But if the needed work includes authenticating users against the local user database then sufficient privilege to do that is necessary.  If there comes a point when privilege is no longer required, then it can be dropped.  There are many ways to manage that sort of thing.  In your FTP server example, a common paradigm would be for the server process itself to run with privilege (as root, or with appropriate capabilities), and [...]

Comment: [...] after it authenticates a user, to start a new session for that user, and in it a separate, unprivileged process to handle the server side of the FTP conversation.

Comment: Note also that for FTP in particular, the main server process also requires privilege to bind a socket to the standard FTP port.  After doing so, however, it does not need to retain privilege to accept connections from the already-established socket.  It is typical in a case like that for the server process itself to drop privileges.  For example, via `setuid()` and `setgid()` to an unprivileged user and group.

Comment: Thanks again for your time, I'll study better the things now and come back if necessary :)